# why an input function cannot follow an output function without an intervening call to fflush?

Tags: c, io

I'm new to C and I was reading a textbook which says that:

Standard I/O streams are full duplex in the sense that programs can perform input and output on the same stream. However, there are poorly documented restrictions on streams

Restriction 1: Input functions following output functions. An input function
cannot follow an output function without an intervening call to fflush, fseek, fsetpos, or rewind

Restriction 2: Output functions following input functions. An output function
cannot follow an input function without an intervening call to fseek,
fsetpos, or rewind, unless the input function encounters an end-of-file.

I'm confused, below is my questions:

Q1-My understanding about the stream buffer is, each stream has two buffers, a read buffer and a write buffer, and is my understanding correct?

Q2-why we have to resposition the current file position or flush the output buffer when input functions following output functions or vice versa?

Comment: Related [C11 7.21.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2): there's no mention of "buffer" in this section of the Standard.

Comment: @pmg: see [7.21.3/3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p3) for "buffer"; buffers are not a required feature, but there is an established API, which associates a buffer with a stream when the stream is associated with a "file" (which is not necessarily what we usually mean by the word.)

Answer (score 0):

> the stream buffer is, each stream has two buffers, a read buffer and a write buffer, ...

Maybe.   2 or 1 buffers are not required, yet buffering is performance practical.

> why we have to....

That is what is needed to meet the specification. Specs were written to provide implementers some latitude - but not too much.

With tight specs, come limited implementation possibilities (no so efficient code).